# WordPress Theme Customization (Marine)

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

**Can anybody help me?**

My client bought a custom WP theme:

http://themeforest.net/item/marine-responsive-wordpress-theme-multipurpose/full_screen_preview/7741798

Having installed the custom theme, fresh out the box it comes with . . . nothing. I have tried recreating the home page that they use for advertising, but so far I have not been able to get anything done.

The theme's advertised home page has a bunch of sections, stacked on top of each other, and I need to create a similar Home page, just with custom designs. I have read through the comments other users have made, I've tried tons of things, but I just can't get a handle on things.

Does anyone have extensive knowledge of shortcodes, widgets and page builder?

I am using a child theme, so that the client can update the actual theme without requiring any re-work from me. I'm pretty decent with PHP, JavaScript, HTML and CSS, but this has me scratching my head.

What kind of information do I need to provide to be seriously useful to someone who might be able to help me with this problem project?

This is the design I need to produce:

http://xnresults.com/WPimg/DCS-FINAL-LAYOUT--01-2.png

All I need is some guidance to get going. If anyone with experience and knowledge wants to make a quick buck, I'd be happy to accommodate that as well - as long as I can learn how to do this stuff myself.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

i think this theme is based on post section and pages.you just have to customize the sections from dashboard according to your need.first go to a section(if thers is any on your dashboard.) and edit it according to your need.if you want to add more new pages just add new section and from right hand side create a new category and assign it to that section now create a page with same name and call the section in query section of dashboard.

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback. I just found out yesterday evening, that the version of the theme I received was missing several parts. I have no idea how that would have happened, but my client re-downloaded the latest version and sent it to me overnight.

I'm hoping that things will be as clear as you stated they should be. Thanks again.

Comment: Shawn Spencer: happy to help u dear....though u can get same themes from here:http://themify.me/